# how do i get an array into a comma delimited string with single quotes in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, delimited

I have tried all the main PowerShell websites and have not found anything yet
can someone please provide a code snippet
that takes an array like this: and wree test the
and converts it to:  'and','wree','test','the'  .

here is some sample code
#Define Variables
`$a = Get-Content 'c:\users\p3110458\PS test.txt'`

`'"' + $($(get-content 'c:\users\p3110458\PS test.txt'  ) -join ',') + '"'`

replace function needs to be written to make this code work.

`$str_var = 123, 654, 283, 1344`
`$str_var = $str_var.Replace(" “, “”)`
`$str_var = “’” + $str_var.Replace(”,", “’,’”) + “’”`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

`$a -join ","` 
`$a -join "''"`

`$b = get-content $a`

#Define Functions
`function append-text {` 
`process{`
`foreach-object {"'"  + $_  +  ",'"}`
`}` 
`}`

#Process Code
`$b | append-text`

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for something like this:

```
123, 654, 283, 1344 -replace '^|$', "'" -join ','
```

Output (a single string):

```
'123','654','283','1344'
```

The above uses the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to effectively enclose each (stringified) array element in `'...'`, and then [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join)s the resulting strings with `,`

Regex `'^|$'` matches both the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) *position* of each element, and replacing them with verbatim `'` effectively places a `'` before and after each element.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @andrewmcg.